# Python Flask Application Manager

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

I am coming from a Java/Tomcat background and was wondering if there is anything out there which could be similar to the Tomcat manager application?

I'm imagining a webapp that I can use to easily deploy and un-deploy Flask based webapps. I guess an analogy to Tomcat would be a WSGI server with a web based manager.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the [deployment story](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/) for Python / WSGI is [not quite as neat](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2011/03/31/python-webapp-package/) as Java's WAR file based deployment. (And, while [Python is not Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html) that doesn't mean that WAR file deployments aren't nice). So you don't have anything that will *quite* match your expectations there - but you may be able to cobble together something similar.

First, you'll want a web server that can easily load and unload WSGI applications without requiring a server restart - the one that immediately jumps to mind is [uwsgi in emperor mode](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Emperor.html) (and here's [an example setup](http://tghw.com/blog/multiple-django-and-flask-sites-with-nginx-and-uwsgi-emperor)).

Second, you need a consistent way lay out your applications so the WSGI file can be picked up / generated.  Something as simple as always having a root-level `app.wsgi` file that can be copied to the directory being watched by `uwsgi` will do.

Third, you'll need a script that can take a web application folder / virtualenv and move / symlink it to the "available applications" folder.  You'll need another one that can add / symlink, touch (to restart) and remove (to shutdown) the `app.wsgi` files from the directory(ies) that `uwsgi` is watching for new vassel applications. If you need to run it across multiple machines (or even just one remote machine) you could use [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/).

Fourth and finally, you'll need a little web application to enable you to manage the WSGI files for these available applications without using the command line.  Since you just spent all this time building some infrastructure for it, why not use [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and deploy it on itself to make sure everything works?

It's not a pre-built solution, but hopefully this at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks @Sean, this pretty much echos what I had in mind as well, I just want to focus more on the actual project that I'm working on rather than building this. Hence was looking for a pre-built solution. This would a good next project!